# How to access older iPhone auto-backups / restore lost Safari cards?

Tags: icloud, safari, backup, time-machine, data

Recently I've lost all my open Safari cards on my iPhone. Since i want to move my data to a new model anyway, I was just disabling wifi every time I plugged it to the charger in order to not let it auto-backup. I did not turn off the backup function, because I was too scared of the iThreat, threatening they'll delete all my iCloud files, backups, photos, etc. if i cancel anything iCloud-related. So sadly, that one time I forgot to turn off the wifi, and it did back up automatically. Since I've tried doing a computer backup many times before on many different PC's and cables, changing settings, including replacing the whole charging port, I couldn't do it, so iCloud backups are the only ones I could make. Now, as you might have guessed, the latest backup doesn't contain any of those lost 48 open cards, and the latest backup i did manually is almost half-year old.

Is there any way I can get access to the older AUTOMATIC iCloud backup? If not, how do I get my cards back? They couldn't just disappear without the trace of I didn't physically press 'delete' button right??

Answer (score 1):

> Recently I've lost all my open Safari cards on my iPhone.

I'm assuming you're referring to your open tabs/windows. These aren't backed up.

> Since i want to move my data to a new model anyway, I was just disabling wifi every time I plugged it to the charger in order to not let it auto-backup.

This, quite frankly, doesn't make sense. Auto-backups to iCloud don't interfere with manual backups to your computer. It also doesn't interfere with backups made on other devices.

> I did not turn off the backup function, because I was too scared of the iThreat, threatening they'll delete all my iCloud files, backups, photos, etc. if i cancel anything iCloud-related.

It tells you that it will remove your iCloud Backup of the current device if you turn it off, because you're turning it off.

> So sadly, that one time I forgot to turn off the wifi, and it did back up automatically. Since I've tried doing a computer backup many times before on many different PC's and cables, changing settings, including replacing the whole charging port, I couldn't do it, so iCloud backups are the only ones I could make.

This is a whole other issue, it seems.

> Now, as you might have guessed, the latest backup doesn't contain any of those lost 48 open cards, and the latest backup i did manually is almost half-year old.

> Is there any way I can get access to the older AUTOMATIC iCloud backup?

iCloud will show you a list of backups you can pick from when you restore your device. There is no guarantee any specific backup other than the latest will be available, but there usually are.

> If not, how do I get my cards back? They couldn't just disappear without the trace of I didn't physically press 'delete' button right??

Again assuming you're referring to the open Safari windows, these aren't backed up. Use bookmarks if you want to save websites.